# How do I check if an item from a list is in another list?

Tags: python, list

I was trying to write a simple Python 3 program and cant find answers.

```
fruits = ["strawberries", "apples", "bananas", "pomegranates", "blueberries", "dragon fruits", "papayas", "pears", "oranges", "mango", "tomatoes", "peaches", "melons", "watermelons"]
favoritefruits = [fruits[0], fruits[2], fruits[3], fruits[7], fruits[8], fruits[13]]

for i in fruits:
    if fruits[i] in favoritefruits:
        print("I'm gonna buy some " + fruits[i] + " because they are one of my favorite fruits.")
    else:
        print("I'm not going to buy " + fruits[i] + ", I don't like them.")
```

Comment: `i` is the fruit itself, so `fruits[i]` would raise an exception (using `str` as an index or something like that). You just want `if i in favoritefruits`

Comment: Can also use string interpolation `print(f"I'm not gonna buy some {fruit}, I don't like 'em.")` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Have Two Lists: `fruits` and `favoritefruits`

```
fruits = ["strawberries", "apples", "bananas", "pomegranates", "blueberries", "dragon fruits", "papayas", "pears", "oranges", "mango", "tomatoes", "peaches", "melons", "watermelons"]
```

```
favoritefruits = [fruits[0], fruits[2], fruits[3], fruits[7], fruits[8], fruits[13]]
```

To iterate you do not need to use `i`.
Instead, just use:

```
for fruit in fruits:
    if fruit in favoritefruits:
        print("I'm gonna buy some " + fruit + " because they are one of my favorite fruits.")
    else:
        print("I'm not going to buy " + fruit + ", I don't like them.")
```

#### Output:

```
I'm gonna buy some strawberries because they are one of my favorite fruits.
I'm not going to buy apples, I don't like them.
I'm gonna buy some bananas because they are one of my favorite fruits.
I'm gonna buy some pomegranates because they are one of my favorite fruits.
I'm not going to buy blueberries, I don't like them.
I'm not going to buy dragon fruits, I don't like them.
I'm not going to buy papayas, I don't like them.
I'm gonna buy some pears because they are one of my favorite fruits.
I'm gonna buy some oranges because they are one of my favorite fruits.
I'm not going to buy mango, I don't like them.
I'm not going to buy tomatoes, I don't like them.
I'm not going to buy peaches, I don't like them.
I'm not going to buy melons, I don't like them.
I'm gonna buy some watermelons because they are one of my favorite fruits.
```

Answer (score 3):

As @wkl has stated, `for i in fruits` will iterate through all fruit **names**, not the index. Replacing `fruits[i]` with `i` (though a more descriptive name is better) will fix the issue:

```py
fruits = ["strawberries", "apples", "bananas", "pomegranates", "blueberries", "dragon fruits", "papayas", "pears", "oranges", "mango", "tomatoes", "peaches", "melons", "watermelons"]
favoritefruits = [fruits[0], fruits[2], fruits[3], fruits[7], fruits[8], fruits[13]]

for fruit in fruits:
    if fruit in favoritefruits:
        print("I'm gonna buy some " + fruit + " because they are one of my favorite fruits.")
    else:
        print("I'm not going to buy " + fruit + ", I don't like them.")
```

Answer (score 0):

`for i in fruits` will return the fruits themselves and not the index and so when you do `fruits[i]` python expects an int but you gave it a string. You can do `for i in range(len(fruits))` so that `fruits[i]` returns the fruit but in your code you only use the index to get the fruit so a much cleaner solution would be to rewrite `for i in fruits` into `for fruit in fruits` and simply use `fruit` inside the loop.